# Can an Azure App Service redirect www to non-www?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to redirect www to non-www at the azure app service level?

I need this at the app service level and not in the configuration file of my app. I have been able to get http to https working under the tls/ssl blade, but I don't see a way to redirect for www.

Do I need another resource like front door or application manager?  I'd like to handle it in the app service itself.

My app server is running a docker container that is using an nginx server.  I'm not an expert with nginx, and haven't been able to get the redirect to work in the nginx configuration.  Plus, I'd like to set this up in my bicep file.

Comment: AFAIK, we cannot redirect URL within the App service, but we can you redirect URL using Azure Front Door or application gateway to non-www.

Answer (score 0):

To rewrite a URL, you need to create a web.config file in your wwwroot folder and put the necessary entries in there, if you don't already have a web.config file for your site.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>  
    <rewrite>  
        <rules>  
          <rule name="Redirect requests to default azure websites domain" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />  
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^yoursite\.azurewebsites\.net$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://yoursite.com/{R:0}" />  
          </rule>  
        </rules>  
    </rewrite>  
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

Original answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/193377/how-to-redirect-in-app-service

Comment: I am not running an app with a web config.

Comment: What Kind of App service are you running (Windows, Linux)? What language are you using? What web server are you using?

Comment: The app service is running a docker image that uses nginx and runs WordPress.  I know how to do this with nginx, which is why I didn't put those details in the question.  I am not asking how to do the redirect, I am asking how to have the app service perform this functionality.
I also need to do an HTTP to HTTPS redirect.  I can do that in nginx, but I did it by selecting https only in the tls blade of the app service.  I was asking if there is a similar way to achieve the www to non-www redirect, so I can put it in a bicep template.